# PHP, variable wont attach to hyperlink

Tags: php

Im trying to send the patient ID through a  hyperlink, tho while it redirects to the correct page it is not sending the information.

```py
<a href="./patientrecord.php?patient_id="<?php $row["patient_id"]?>><?php echo $row["surname"];?></a>
```

Comment: Maybe `<?php echo $row["patient_id"]?>` or `<?= $row["patient_id"]?>` will solve the problem

Comment: <a href="./patientrecord.php?patient_id=$row["patient_id"]><?php echo $row["surname"];?></a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you are going to echo the variable

Echoing a variable:

```
<?= $echoable_variable_here ?> // Use <?= ?> tags
or
<?php echo $echoable_variable_here ?> // Use echo inside <?php ?> tags
```

Edit: You have placed echo outside the href attribute tag

Therefore,

Change this:

```
<a href="./patientrecord.php?patient_id="<?php $row["patient_id"]?>><?php echo $row["surname"];?></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="./patientrecord.php?patient_id=<?php echo $row["patient_id"]?>"><?php echo $row["surname"];?></a>
```

or to:

```
<a href="./patientrecord.php?patient_id=<?= $row["patient_id"] ?>"><?php echo $row["surname"];?></a>
```

Comment: in 2nd case you don't echo variable name?

Comment: Still nothing, the $row["patient_id"] definetly exists as it can be echoed out, but neither of those send it to the patientrecord.php. Would there be any reason that wouldnt be working, like could I have forgot something somewhere else? It displays the surname, but the url is "patientrecord.php?patient_id=".

Comment: try with my comment.

Comment: @LordPotato have you tried using **$_GET['patient_id']** inside patientrecord.php file?

Comment: @MohitKumar **<?= $variable ?>** is a shortcut for **<?php echo $variable ?>. Check: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: @JohnAbelardoMananganII yes, it returns nothing.

Comment: try with my comment please

Comment: @LordPotato are you sure **$row['patient_id']** is not null or empty?

Comment: @JohnAbelardoMananganII i dont think so, echo $row['patient_id'] outputs data.

Comment: @LordPotato just try with my code & let me know please?

Comment: @LordPotato I have updated my answer above, can you try it? it is based on MohitKumar's comment

Comment: I'm not sure how forgiving PHP is when using the shortcut code, but both of the two options are omitting semicolons. try `<?= $row['patient_id']; ?>` or `<?php echo $row['patient_id']; ?>`

Comment: @JohnAbelardoMananganII and MohitKumar, it worked, thank you to the fullest extent for your help. Words can't properly describe how much I appreciate this.

Comment: No problem, more power to PHP. You should thank @MohitKumar

Comment: @JohnAbelardoMananganII   for what you should thank?

Comment: @LordPotato what happened?